# Automatic SQL Calculate

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a test table:

PiggyBank_Current

```
- Name (Primary Key)
-- Jackson
- Value
-- 0
```

PiggyBank_Default

```
- Name 
-- Jackson
- value
-- 100
```

PiggyBank_Earn

```
- Name
-- Jackson
- Value
-- 20
```

Is it possible that everytime I add a new Jackson earning record to PiggyBank_Earn that it automatic calculate all Jackson earning then add it with the default. The total will then replace the value on table PiggyBank_Current value that the person name is equal to Jackson? So for this example it would be 120 total.

Comment: you can use triggers. Please detail better your goal

Comment: @JoeTaras  The requirement is that for every insert into `PiggyBank_Earn`, the sum of all `Value`s in `PiggyBank_Earn` is added to the `Value` held in `PiggyBank_Default` for that particular `Name`, and that total is used to overwrite the `Value` in `PiggyBank_Current` for the same `Name`.

Comment: Please, don't use `nvarchar` fields (`name`) as PK. Use `uniqueidentifier` or `identity` for that purpose.

Comment: @iamdave: Yes, trigger is the solution! So, now I upvote gofr1 answer, because is the main road

Answer (score 1):

You can use trigger for that purpose. I used `id` instead of `[name]` to join tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PiggyBank_Earn_Trigger
ON PiggyBank_Earn
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  id,
        SUM([val]) as [value]
FROM (
    SELECT  d.id,
            SUM(d.[value]) as [val]
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN PiggyBank_Default d
        ON i.id = d.id
    GROUP BY d.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  e.id,
            SUM(i.[value]) as [val]
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN PiggyBank_Earn e
        ON i.id = e.id
    GROUP BY e.id
) as t
)

MERGE PiggyBank_Current as target
USING cte as source
ON target.id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [value] = source.[value]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEn
    INSERT VALUES (source.id, source.[value]);
```

It collects in CTE all `id` from `inserted` and gets sums from 2 tables. Then `MERGE` `PiggyBank_Current` table.